# Add a custom sound to UILocalNotification soundName

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

What am trying to do is, allow user to record an audio then use this recorded audio as an alarm sound, I have managed to do the recording part, but I can't set the recorded audio to UILocalNotification sound. I have google it for a while, all I found people saying it's not possible to use a custom sound unless it's in the main bundle. But there is this app called AidaReminder that managed to do what I want, so does anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW6 :

> The sound files can be in the main bundle of the client app **or in the
>   `Library/Sounds` folder of the app’s data container**.

(emphasis and formatting added)

It's actually the first time I notice this, not sure this has always been the case or if that was added in a recent iOS version.

Comment: It was always like this.

Comment: @user2037296, if the answer helped you, feel free to up vote and/or accept it.